# import-im6.q16: not authorized `boto3' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I use AWS CLI . i installed boto3 and i try run that code. i have three errors

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# Get list of objects for indexing
images=[('afridi.jpg','Shahid Afridi'),
   ('sakib.jpg','Sakib Al Hasan'),
   ('kohli.jpg','Birat Kohli'),
   ('masrafi.jpg','Mashrafe Bin Mortaza'),
   ('ganguli.jpg','Sourav Ganguly')
  ]
```

## Iterate through list to upload objects to S3

```
for image in images:
    file = open(image[0],'rb')
    object = s3.Object('taifur12345bucket',image[0])
    ret = object.put(Body=file,
               Metadata={'FullName':image[1]}
               )
```

the errors

```
import-im6.q16: not authorized `boto3' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
./code1.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./code1.py: line 2: `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')'
```

Comment: Have you set your Access Key and Secret Key in `~/.aws/credentials` or your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is missing the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the top.  Because of this, your script is being run by the `bash` shell, not by the Python interpreter.  `bash` doesn't understand Python code, hence the errors you are getting.

Add the shebang line to the top of your script and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running this code from a permissioned ec2 instance, you will need to configure your credentials appropriately.

[see configuration section here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html)

Comment: i did all of this configuration and the same errors